# How to add on one day to dates in dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, timedelta

I have a dictionary which I created from a pandas df (see below). This dictionary has a 'Key' and dates. I want to add 1 day to each date in the dictionary. One way I did this was to create a new column in the df that is one day plus the column which holds the dates and then stored that in the dictionary. But I am interested in doing this without having to add a column.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['10003', '10003', '10003', '10003', '10003','10003','10034'], 
               'Num1': [12,13,30,12,13,13,16],
               'Num2': [121,122,122,124,125,126,127],
              'admit': [2015019, 20150124, 20150206,20150211,20150220,20150407,20150211],
          'discharge': [20150123, 20150202, 20150211,20150220,20150304,20150410,20150211]})
df['admit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['admit'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['discharge'] = pd.to_datetime(df['discharge'], format='%Y%m%d')

{'10003': {Timestamp('2015-01-09 00:00:00'),
           Timestamp('2015-01-24 00:00:00'),
           Timestamp('2015-02-06 00:00:00'),
           Timestamp('2015-02-11 00:00:00'),
           Timestamp('2015-02-20 00:00:00'),
           Timestamp('2015-04-07 00:00:00')},
'10034': {Timestamp('2015-02-11 00:00:00')}}

d1 = df.groupby('Key')['admit'].apply(set).to_dict() # how the original dictionary is formed above
df['admitplus1'] = ['admit'] + timedelta(days=1)
d2 = df.groupby('Key')['admitplus1'].apply(set).to_dict() # how I formed the new dictionary with an added column to my df
```

Comment: What is `Timestamp`.. is it a variable? a datetime object?

Comment: datetime object. It is stored in the `['admit']` column.

Comment: If that was a dictionary of sets, I would say `{k:set(t + timedelta(days=1) for t in v) for k,v in D.items()}`? But it seems you have some pandas involved.

Comment: Why just don't push Timestamps to the array? and access to dictionary's keys?

Comment: Can you share how the dataframe looks like?